# How can i use odometer in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a react native app where I want to use some animation like odometer. But I am not finding any way to do that. I have got one dependency [react-odometer](https://github.com/dearfrankg/react-odometer) . Although I am not being able to do anything with this. I want to generate some random numbers with the help of odometer animation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-speedometer

Comment: The link you have shared does speedometer I guess. Can I do odometer with that? @sachinmathew